# Will redis-sentinel support end?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel

I am currently using redis-py, and redis-sentinel.

I heard that redis-sentinel support will end, is that true?
Will only redis-cluster be supported in the future?

Comment: I didn't hear that rumor. In any case, StackOverflow isn't intended for this type of questions... I suggest you post this in the mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/redis-db

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I will post to the mailing list.: groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/redis-db –